# Training set does not have missing values, but test set does. How to handle?

Tags: missing-data, mice

For a modeling challenge, I was given a training and test set separately. Since my training set did not have a substantial number of missing records, I omitted all rows with NA's. And trained my model on a complete data set.

However, my test data set also contains NA's. I don't have the luxury to remove any test data set rows as I need to generate predictions for each row. How should I approach this problem? Would it make sense to use imputation methods (e.g., MICE) on just the test data set, even though I didn't need to impute anything in the training data set?

Answer (score 3):

Figure out why missingness would occur. Is it random stuff that just happens and tells you very little (e.g. questionnaires randomly got lost in the post), something that might be explainable through the observed data (e.g. you have longitudinal data from patients and when values get worse patients eventually quit the study, which one can more or less foresee from recorded worsening values), or is the missingness for reasons you may not be able to tell from the data and/or might tell you something by itself (e.g. is it possible that patients don't turn up again, because they died and you don't have that information? Or missing time since last order tells you that there were no previous orders etc.)? That would approximately correspond to MCAR, MAR or MNAR / other weird scenarios. The first two should be scenarios that a suitable form of e.g. multiple imputation can address (not sure I'd use MICE, because the chaining of the equations tends to induce annoying limitations, but e.g. the full latent normal model as e.g. in the `amelia` R package could be one option). The last type of scenarios needs a lot more human input and is much less easy to address. If you understand the problem enough to exclude that situation, going for a suitable multiple imputation seems like one possible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would make sense.

First, note that you can omit rows with missing data during training provided you are sure that your data is [missing completely at random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Missing_completely_at_random) (MCAR). Otherwise, you should apply some imputation technique during training. And even if you think that the number of observations you would omit is not relevant, it wouldn't hurt to also apply imputation for comparison of results.

But, independent of whether you used imputation in training, if you want to apply it to new data with missing values, you can apply imputation on the independent variables, and [`mice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) is a good choice.